# Como aplicar los estilos a toda las columnas?

Tags: css

**Si tengo:**

```css
#principales td{

margin: 20px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
     <table align="center">
    <td><b>Simbolos matemáticos</b></td>
  </table>
  <tr id="principales"> 
    <td>Simbolo</td>
    <td>Nombre</td>
    <td>Significado</td>
  </tr>
  
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

*En el código CSS, programé:*

```
#principales td{
margin:20px;
}
```

***Por qué no es aplicado el margen a todos los*** `<td>` **?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estás creando la tabla con la estructura correcta, estás agregando una tabla dentro de otra tabla sin utilizar `tr` ni `td`, entonces el navegador al interpretar eso te crea una tabla distinta a la que esperas sin el `id="principales"`.

Además si quieres agregar un encabezado a la tabla lo mejor es usar `th`.

El siguiente código resuelve tu problema:

```css
#principales td{
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Simbolos matemáticos</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="principales"> 
        <td>Simbolo</td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>Significado</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: que hace colspan?

Comment: Es para que el `th` utilice 3 celdas de la tabla, de esta manera se mostrará sobre las celdas Simbolo, Nombre, Significado. Si lo remueves, el `th` utilizará una sola celda y se mostrará sólo sobre Simbolo.

Comment: Modifiqué el código para que muestre los bordes de las celdas, tal vez así te sea más claro lo que hace.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#principales div{
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div align="center" colspan="3"><b>Simbolos matemáticos</b></div>
    <div id="principales"> 
        <div>Simbolo</div>
        <div>Nombre</div>
        <div>Significado</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

corrijo, no uses tablas ya que pueden dar esos problemas, si quieres conservar la tabla prueba con usar padding en vez de margin